# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/foobranch' by N commits - WHAT commits?

Tags: git

When git status reports "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/foobranch' by N commits." I want to know EXACTLY which commits. as in give me a list. They are not at the top of the log and I don't want to manually diff the logs. Is there a git command to just show me the N commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find them, you need to use [Git's revision specifications](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  In this case you want *commits reachable from my branch head, but not reachable from `origin/foobranch`:*

```
git log origin/foobranch..foobranch
```

or:

```
git log foobranch ^origin/foobranch
```

(both syntaxes have the same meaning—`A..B` means `B ^A`).

(I like to do this with `--graph --decorate --oneline` as well, a lot.)

You can compute the upstream of any branch automatically:

```
branch@{upstream}
```

will do that.  The upstream of the *current* branch is available with:

```
@{upstream}
```

These can be shortened to `@{u}` (with or without the branch name).  As of Git 2.13, you can use `@{U}` as well, i.e., just hold down shift while typing.

The current branch can be abbreviated as `HEAD` or (since Git 1.8.5) just`@`; in places where this makes sense, it can be omitted entirely.  So:

```
[alias]
    outgoing = log --oneline @{u}..
```

is the alias I use for *what commits would `git push` push?*

Comment: A little improvement: `git log @{u}..@` means the same, is shorter to type and does not make assumptions about `origin`. `@{u}` is short for `@{upstream}` and is documented in the mentioned manual page.

Comment: @A.H.: true, and I should have mentioned it, but it's worth noting that Git is simply substituting in the configured upstream of the current branch when using `@{u}`. Also `@{u}` isn't available in some very old versions of Git (pre-1.7.0, probably very rare these days).